# Why is html,body{height:100%} causing a scroll bar to appear?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website that has a 'panel div on the left, and 'content' div on the right, both contained within `<body>`, and I want them to dynamically expand height to the size of the window. The problem is, when I use `html,body{height:100%}`, there is a scroll bar appearing. I'm hesitant to post full code of what I'm doing, but it is doing this still with a stripped down to:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <STYLE>
          html, body {height:100%}
        </STYLE>
      <BODY>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

so I don't think anything I'm doing could be messing with it...

I will try to provide more info upon request.

Comment: Tell us what your browser is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, up-to-date Chrome, and IE7 are the only ones I had access to.

Comment: For the record, the OP is using Chrome 29.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HTML/BODY got standard padding/margin going on

try:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <STYLE>
      html, body {height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;}
    </STYLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's actually `margin`.

Comment: Also when dealing with values of `0`, it is recommended to remove any unit specification (`%` in this case)

Comment: if you insert only padding:0%; it still works for me thou :) but edited :)

Comment: @DennisAnderson Great, thanks so much! I've taught myself some very basic html/CSS/JS, but I don't know the ins and outs... Picked your answer because you described the issue and gave code solution that I can learn from :)

Answer (score 10):

`<body>` has 8 pixels of margin around it by default, which falls outside the `100%` height.

You need to remove that.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following attributes to your body:

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

Comment: Full sentences are appreciated.